# Hubble telescope: forces and torques due to radiation pressure

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, photons, torque, space

The [Hubble telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble_Space_Telescope) spacecraft uses six [rate gyroscopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_gyro) for orientation sensing. It is well known that even the best [inertial measuring units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_navigation_system) accumulate *drift* or *integration errors* due to bias and noise on the order of $50 \;m/hr$. However, the Hubble telescope has a RMS tracking error on the order of $2^\circ\times10^{-6}$ as explained in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QkFyzVYg1p0&t=665s) recent talk. Clearly, this implies that the sensor ([gyroscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroscope) and [accelerometer](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/accelerometer-basics/all)) bias is accurately estimated up to a relative error which is on the order of $10^{-6}$, which is possible in this case by estimating the external disturbances consisting of the following phenomenon with possibly other unlisted phenomenon.

1. Gravity turn, that is, the effect of the gravitational field of the earth on the spacecraft which attempts to turn it.
2. Magnetic forces due to the magnetic field of the earth.
3. Solar forces due to transfer of momentum from photons (directly incoming from the sun or reflected off the earth's surface).

The phenomenon #1 can be precisely quantified by using Newton's law of gravitation and sensors similar to the standard [gravimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravimetry#Gravimeter), while the phenomenon # 2 can be precisely estimated by sensing the magnetic field of the earth using sensors similar to the standard [magnetometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetometer). However, it is unclear how the phenomenon # 3 is measured.

> 1. How can the solar forces due to transfer of momentum from photons on the Hubble space telescope be precisely estimated?
> 2. What other external physics affect the motion of the Hubble telescope spacecraft?

[image]